# Time upward counter

Tags: javascript, loops, timer, nested, clock

I am quite new to programming and one of the tutorial classes I am taking gave me an assignment to create a javascript script to display all seconds of a day.

I completed the assignment myself with some basic code:

```js
function Time() {
  var hours = 12;
  var minutes = 0;
  var seconds = 0;
  var amorpm = 1;
  var counter = 0;
  var endtime = 86400;
  while (counter < endtime) {
    if (amorpm <= 12) {
      document.writeln(fixTime(hours) + ":" + fixTime(minutes) + ":" + fixTime(seconds) + "AM");
    } else if (amorpm > 12) {
      document.writeln(fixTime(hours) + ":" + fixTime(minutes) + ":" + fixTime(seconds) + "PM");
    } else {
      break;
    }

    if (seconds < 59) {
      seconds++;
    } else {
      if (minutes < 59) {
        minutes++;
      } else {
        ampm++;
        if (hours < 12) {
          hours++;
        } else {
          hours = 1;
        }
        minutes = 0;
      }
      seconds = 0;
    }
    counter = counter + 1;
  }
}

function fixTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  };
  return i;
}
```

And the output is fully correct.

However, one of the criterias was to use "nested loops" and for the life of me I am kinda having trouble figuring out how to do the same thing with nested loops.

I am guessing I could use for-loops with i++-s to count seconds and minutes, or a few while loops, but all of that seems kinda like unnecessary baggage to me.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 12 hour clock with AM and PM. You can create 4 for loops. 3 for hours, minutes and seconds each and one to switch from AM to PM and nest them.

```js
for (var min = 0; min <= 59; min++) { //Loop for Min Count
  for (var sec = 0; sec <= 59; sec++) { //Loop for seconds count
    console.log("12" + ":" + (min < 10 ? "0" + min : min) + ":" + (sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec) + " AM");

  }
}
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) { //loop to switch from AM to PM
  for (var hour = 1; hour <= 12 - i; hour++) { //Loop for Hour Count
    for (var min = 0; min <= 59; min++) { //Loop for Min Count
      for (var sec = 0; sec <= 59; sec++) { //Loop for seconds count
        if (i == 0 && hour != 12) {
          console.log((hour < 10 ? "0" + hour : hour) + ":" + (min < 10 ? "0" + min : min) + ":" + (sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec) + " AM");
        } else {
          console.log((hour < 10 ? "0" + hour : hour) + ":" + (min < 10 ? "0" + min : min) + ":" + (sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec) + " PM");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works the way I was trying to do it. But the problem with a clock is that there is really no 00 in hours, so after 12:59:59 it needs to start from 01:00:00. Also there was a requirement of starting from 12:00:00.

Comment: btw after 12:59:59 it is starting from 01:00: 00

Comment: Yes now it works perfectly! This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [`for loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) for ***hours***, ***minutes*** and ***seconds*** each and nest them.

You can take `mod 12` of hour for *AM / PM*.

```js
for (let h = 0; h < 24; h++) {
  for (let m = 0; m < 60; m++) {
    for (let s = 0; s < 60; s++) {
      // 24 hour
      document.write(`<div>${h.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${m.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${s.toString().padStart(2, "0")}</div>`);
      // 12 hour am/pm
      //document.write(`<div>${(h % 12).toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${m.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${s.toString().padStart(2, "0")} ${h < 12 ? "AM" : "PM"}</div>`);
    }
  }
}
```